# Postgres inner json update

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

```
{
    "travel": {
        "arrival": {
            "time": "2020-09-03T10:05:00.000Z",
            "type": "Contract",
            "driver": "saman",
            "provider": "ideal",
            "vehicleno": null
        },
        "departure": {
            "time": "2020-09-03 16:55",
            "type": "Contract",
            "driver": "saman",
            "provider": null,
            "vehicleno": null
        }
    },
    "serviceend": "2020-09-03T11:15:00.000Z",
    "costsheetno": "AA 67856",
    "servicestart": "2020-09-03T10:10:00.000Z"
}
```

How to set costsheet->'travel'->'departure'->'time'=null ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [ask] a question.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_set()` like that:

```
jsonb_set(costsheet, '{travel,departure,time}', 'null')
```